# Woocommerce before and after shop loop not works

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have created a shortcode to show all woocommerce products in a new page with all woocommerce filter and pagination but it seems only products are showing

```
ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' ); //this would show post count and filter ?>
            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' ); //this would show pagination ?>

        <?php endif;?>

        <?php
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
        <?php
        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $column . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
```

According to woocommerce archive-products.php template `woocommerce_before_shop_loop` should show count and filter

And `woocommerce_after_shop_loop` show pagination but here its not working.Any alternative to show them?

Full shortcode for wc-visual composer : https://pastebin.com/crv4jwsz

Answer (score 1):

In core WooCommerce, the pagination is added via the `woocommerce_pagination()` function hooked to `woocommerce_after_shop_loop`, and the sorting and result counts are output by the `woocommerce_result_count()` and `woocommerce_catalog_ordering()` functions. If you look at the source for these functions, you can see that they display according to the *main* `$wp_query`, which will not contain any products because you're querying posts with your own WP_Query.

So this might be one of those *very* rare occasions where `query_posts()` would be the right thing to do. If you use `query_posts()` in place of a secondary WP_Query, then those template functions should reflect your custom query.

```
ob_start();

query_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' ); //this would show post count and filter ?>
    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' ); //this would show pagination ?>

<?php endif;?>

<?php 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
wp_reset_query(); 

return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $column . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
```

Take note of the `wp_reset_query()`, that's very important here.

I'm not sure pagination will work correctly though, you might need to use your own instance of `paginate_links()`, refer to [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) in the codex for examples of using `paginate_links()` with a custom query.